# Switching one Azure App Service's codebase for different one after .NET Core version rewrite

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

We have a .NET Core 2.1 Web App on Azure as an App Service. We deploy it to Azure via Visual Studio 2017's publish option (though it is also in a Git repo). It has a bunch of custom domains and SSL on all of them provided by Azure.

We've written a new version of the web app in .NET Core 3.1, in VS 2019. Identical functionality but written from the ground up rather than trying to upgrade the existing 2.1 version.

There's no staging version online as such - instead we develop on local machines and then just use test domains online that use the same service but where the environment is switched to use dev DBs and bucket locations etc, which is one of the reasons to write a new app rather than upgrade it, also, it just seemed cleaner and I saw that people had some issues when doing upgrades...

Is there an easy way to switch/publish the new web app/code into the current Azure App Service, to replace the old one? Or will I need to create a new App Service and then create all the custom domains, SSL etc there after removing them from the old one?

Or could I perhaps switch to git deployment and push the entire new project in over the old one - would that work or just create some kind of disaster?

Comment: how about using slots? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots

Comment: Oh! That looks like it might work if I deploy to that slot via the new git repo... I'll check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually no issue when pushing a new application version to your app service, even if it uses a new version of .NET Core.
You have to consider two things:

- Windows AppService Plan: .NET Core 3.1 runtime has been rolled out worldwide, while the SDK has not (yet). When in doubt, use self-contained deployment.
- Linux AppService Plan: You need to select the desired runtime version in the portal. Using e.g. [Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment) you can set the runtime version at the same time as you publish the new version. Not sure how VisualStudio handles this.

As a general recommendation, you should follow silents suggestion of using [slot deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) to have as little impact for your customers as possible. Each slot can have e.g. a different .NET runtime version, so you can test everything on the staging slots.

Comment: And depending on how the app is written (i.e. if there are no breaking database schema changes, etc), you can rollback the 3.1 app with another slot swap if things go sideways right after launch.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate the slot idea and return to this later in the week to let you know how it goes and if this works out.

Comment: So slots seem to work, I have the two codebases and different version core apps side by side and I can test one pretty well without making it live. Only issue that that custom domains and ssl can't be tested due to DNS pointing at the wrong CNAME obviously!