# Azure Web App deployment slots, can I swap a slot app for the main production, then delete the old one?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I think I misunderstood Azure Web App deployment slots and have used them incorrectly.

We have a .NET Core 2.1 Web App that we wanted to upgrade to Core 3.1. Rather than upgrade the existing we wrote a new one from the ground up so we could refactor it a little at the same time.

So I created a new deployment slot in Azure and added the new Web App via its (different) GitHub repo. That's fine, the new slot Web App loaded fine and after testing we decided to switch to the new version.

On the go-live I removed all the custom domains from the 2.1 version, and added them to the 3.1 version, along with SSL (there are lots of domains that use the same web app via DNS mappings, which I updated to point to the new slot's CNAME), tested this and it all worked fine. I hit 'swap slots' and essentially nothing happened - the 2.1 app stays as 'Production', and 3.1 is still the a 'slot app'.

Now I've stopped the 2.1 app, and all our traffic is flowing to the 3.1 slot version, but this strikes me as a problem! I need to get rid of the 2.1 version!

Any ideas how to solve this? i.e. how to make (from the pic) 'eadgen-GenV2' the main/production slot, so I can delete the original 'eadgen'?

[image: Azure slots]

ref: [my original question about this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883531/switching-one-azure-app-services-codebase-for-different-one-after-net-core-ver)

Comment: I think eadgen cannot be deleted, because it defaults to your unique webapp name, and it ’s generate since you created the webapp. You should only delete temporary slots.

Answer (score 0):

eadgen is your default slot and eadgen-GenV2 is a temporary slot, I think you can only delete the temporary slot. You can try to use this:

[image]

What will be swapped is:

> General settings, such as framework version, 32/64-bit, web sockets
>   App settings (can be configured to stick to a slot)
>
> Connection strings (can be configured to stick to a slot)
>
> Handler mappings
>
> Public certificates
>
> WebJobs content
>
> Hybrid connections
>
> Virtual network integration
>
> Service endpoints
>
> Azure Content Delivery Network

From the description of the documentation it seems to be able to change the framework version.

This is the doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#swap-two-slots

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything, as I said in my post - I tried the swap. The git repo of the production app was the old one still, and custom domains, ssl etc were also the same - nothing of the new slot version switched that I could see. I need the 'production' to be my new version slot app - git, domains, ssl etc!